# Custom Menu in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im using wordpress 3.0.1 version. My current theme 2010. I had my own theme,i want to create a custom menu for that theme. Can any one give me the code for files in theme

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct was to tell you to go Google this.  But [here's](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/getting-started-with-wordpress-custom-menus/) a great tutorial to get you started.

Basically, you have to do the following:

### Register the custom menu

```
add_action('init', 'register_custom_menu');

function register_custom_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('custom_menu', __('Custom Menu'));
}
```

### Tell your `header.php` file to use the custom menu

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'custom_menu')); ?>
```

### Define your custom menu in the UI

Go to Appearance » Menus to create and customize a new menu.